# Implementing Support Vector Machine - EFFICIENTLY computing gram-matrix K

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I'm implementing SVM for mnist data in Python, for now I'm using cvxopt for solving QP and getting alphas back.

But my problem is computing K-gram matrix ** EFFICIENTLY **, I started with only two class (digits 6 and 0), number of training examples less first 1k, next 10K.

To compute whole 1k x 1k matrix faster, I'm using Process, and giving different raws to compute. But still it takes like 2min- its rbf - gaussian. (10k one is still running!)

If anyone worked on it or may be Python lovers can help me here that would be great!

PS: If someone don't know computing gram-matrix, here is detail:
Its simple:

```
for i in range(1k):
    for j in range(1k):
         for K[i,j] = some_fun(x[i], x[j])
```

where some_fun - is dot product or fancy gaussian.

I'm using python 2.7, numpy and Mac Air 4G RAM, 128G Solid state.

[EDIT] If anyone ever comes here! Yes SVM DOES take longer ... and if you are doing multi classification then you have to calculate k-gram matrix again .. so its gonna take long so I would suggest that implement algorithm and check it twice and let it run over night! But you gonna see good result next day thats for sure! :)

Comment: Are you implementing it just for practice or do you just need to use SVM?  [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) provides an SVM library.

Comment: Implementing SVM is a hard task, and if you are looking for efficiency I wouldn't use python. Even if you want to be able to use it from python I would do it as an extension in C or C++

Comment: @BrenBarn implementing it

Comment: @Pedrom could you give some more detail on your comment ".. as an extension in C ..."

Comment: @codemuncher python is written in c and can have additional functionality added by [writing custom c code](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html). The extension run faster than native python.

Comment: @johnthexiii so you mean same for loop will work faster in C? is it? I never tried custom c in Python, but would like to see, if it works faster as this simple calculation is killing me

Comment: @codemuncher, before you go writing any c you should checkout [scikits svm source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/svm), maybe you'll be able to find out what is slowing your implementation down.

Comment: Most likely the dot product, you can use a BLAS library to speed this up or scikit which ships with these kinds of optimizations.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut still wondering .. as my x is a vector of size 784! this is killing me :(((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using numpy, right? You should get big speedups by using numpy's matrix operations to compute the full matrix at once, rather than doing slow Python loops to find each pairwise evaluation. For example, if we assume that `x` is a row-instance data matrix (one row per data point, one column per dimension):

```
# get a matrix where the (i, j)th element is |x[i] - x[j]|^2
# using the identity (x - y)^T (x - y) = x^T x + y^T y - 2 x^T y
pt_sq_norms = (x ** 2).sum(axis=1)
dists_sq = np.dot(x, x.T)
dists_sq *= -2
dists_sq += pt_sq_norms.reshape(-1, 1)
dists_sq += pt_sq_norms

# turn into an RBF gram matrix
km = dists_sq; del dists_sq
km /= -2 * sigma**2
np.exp(km, km)  # exponentiates in-place
```

Generating data by `np.random.normal(size=(1000, 784))`, this takes 70ms on my quad-core i5 iMac. Upping it to 10k data points, it takes just under 7 seconds.

[sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L322) works similarly, though it has some extra input checking and support for sparse matrices and such.

It's also worth noting that in python 2, you should be looping over `xrange(1000)`, not `range(1000)`. `range` will actually construct a list object to loop over, which takes up some time and maybe more importantly memory. For 10,000 you're probably okay, but this can cause serious problems if your loops get too big.

Comment: @yauheni_selivonchyk I previously had `sigma` here where I should have had `sigma ** 2`; that's probably the issue. (I also made an edit to make it slightly more efficient.) If it's still a problem, you'll have to be more descriptive about the problem, or just use sklearn's `rbf_kernel` (which does basically the same thing).

Comment: I have trouble understanding `km *= (-sigma**2 / 2)`. Wouldn't it be `km *= (-1/2*sigma**2)`? the RBF kernel is `exp(-||x_i - x_j||^2 / 2*sigma^2)` right?

Comment: @Seb You're right (except your parentheses are wrong in the proposed fix); I think I was using a different parameterization `exp(- gamma ||x - y||^2)` at first but mangled it. Fixed now.